# webdrivermanager :java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:'void org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setDefaultConnectionConfig

Tags: java, mockito, webdrivermanager-java

While initializing chrome browser using webdrivermanager using mockito framework, java 17 and chromebrowser version 118 but getting error as

```
"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.hc.client5.http.impl.io.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.setDefaultConnectionConfig(org.apache.hc.client5.http.config.ConnectionConfig)'

    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.online.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:121)
    at io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager.setup(WebDriverManager.java:413)
    at com.ec.demo.iud.BrowserTest.setupClass(BrowserTest.java:34)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
```

My code:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class BrowserTest {

    //@Mock
    static
    WebDriver driver;
    
    @BeforeAll
    static void setupClass() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Seleniumdriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        //driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver= WebDriverManager.chromedriver().getWebDriver();
        WebDriverManager.getInstance("chrome").setup();
    }
    
    @AfterEach
    void teardown() {
        driver.quit();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void test() {

     driver.get("https://bonigarcia.dev/selenium-webdriver-java/");
     String title = driver.getTitle();

       
    }
}
```

I tried and execute above code to initialize driver getting error.